# PHP PDF creation A3, A4 and A5

Tags: php, printing, pdf-generation

I'm looking at generating PDFs to output various types of document sizes, A3, A4, A5 using PHP.

Currently I have a div that has various divs within this area that are positioned absolutely.

What I'm looking to do though is to have this div a fixed height a width, but when I save the contents, it can be used for A4, A3 and A5 print sizes.

What's the best way of achieving this?

Thanks

EDIT:

I am also trying to add a full width background image for each type?

Also, does the div need to be a specific height/width in order to create each document?

I'd like to have an 'area' where I can view the HTML of document. So, if I select A3, it will then save the PDF as A3, with the background image full width and all the positioned divs in the correct places.

Comment: Check [this](http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php)

Comment: You could use the `mPDF` library for PHP - You only pass it the HTML source and it generates You the PDF file while in `mpdf` constructor You set the desired paper format.

Comment: Ok, what about background images? Do these need to be a specific height/width for each page size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [MPDF](http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php)

mPDF is a PHP class which generates PDF files from UTF-8 encoded HTML. It is based on [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/) and [HTML2FPDF](http://html2fpdf.sourceforge.net/), with a number of enhancements.

I wrote mPDF to output PDF files 'on-the-fly' from my website, handling different languages. It is slower than the original scripts e.g. HTML2FPDF and produces larger files when using Unicode fonts, but support for CSS styles etc. has been much enhanced - see the [features](http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/enhancements).

Please see the [examples](http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/examples), and feel free to [download](http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/download) it. There is quite an extensive online [documentation manual](http://mpdf1.com/manual/) for mPDF.

Here is the list of arguments you can pass to default constructor.

```
$mpdf = new mPDF('',    // mode - default ''
 '',    // format - A4, for example, default ''
 0,     // font size - default 0
 '',    // default font family
 15,    // margin_left
 15,    // margin right
 16,     // margin top
 16,    // margin bottom
 9,     // margin header
 9,     // margin footer
 'L');  // L - landscape, P - portrait
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Did you create various page sizes though, A4, A3 and A5 using this library?

Comment: Yes, you can create A4 A5 A3 pages, you just have to pass that argument. If you look at few example it will help

Comment: Ok, so If I have a main wrapper div that contains the HTML that I want to output as a PDF, does it have to be a specific height/width for each page size?

Comment: Lets say you want to create A4 size PDF, then if the content is bigger than that, It will take rest of the content to next page. you don't have to do anything here.

Comment: Ok, I have a div 800x600, that has various divs inside that are position absolutely. What would happen if this is outputted as A3?

Comment: If div is smaller than the page, It will work according to the CSS applied, IF div is large than the page size then it will wrap the text around.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22962/discussion-between-user789122-and-dhruv-patel)

Answer (score -1):

A good way to do it is **the class FPDF**, and its extension **TFPDF** that bring UTF8 support.

[Fpdf Homepage](http://fpdf.org/?lang=en)

[Tfpdf Script](http://fpdf.org/en/script/script92.php)

I have used it sometimes and it works fine.

Answer (score -1):

You can use an API like the ones from htm2pdf.co.uk

Answer (score -1):

Try to use **[wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/)** is from google i think, it works with WebKit so it has a huge html compatiblity, and also has a option to specific the page-size output including A4,A3,etc or specific a custom size, the problem is that is a executable application , that's means you need to run it on Linux/Windows, and in some cases for archive that you need to ask to the hosting provider to give you run permission for that application

other option is http://pdfcrowd.com/html-to-pdf-api/ , is an API , that lets you create pdf and it has a huge compatibility with HTML aswell, is a Pay service , i think they have some free account but you have very limited amount of pdf you can generate

i strongly recomend wkhtmltopdf , the html convertion is almost perfect and free