# how to create print view with A4 page size and fix border per page

Tags: php, html, css, printing, laravel

i have a big page on html gen from php 
and in want to create print view with html and css 
i use print.css style to create this page 
then have some question :

1. how to create **A4** size page
2. how to create **border** for all pages and for per page
3. how to create **fix size** view in any browser ?
4. have **php** class for generate this ?

thanks for your answers :)

Comment: u can use Javascript for it. "window.print()" prints ur current window.

Answer (score 1):

this may be help u out

```
<div id="printpage">  
 //blah blah
</div>  

<a href="#" onclick="printdiv()">Print</a>

function printdiv()
{
    //your print div data
    //alert(document.getElementById("printpage").innerHTML);
    var newstr=document.getElementById("printpage").innerHTML;

    var header='<header><div align="center"><h3 style="color:#EB5005"> Your HEader </h3></div><br></header><hr><br>'

    var footer ="Your Footer";

    //You can set height width over here
    var popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'width=1100,height=600');
    popupWin.document.open();
    popupWin.document.write('<html> <body onload="window.print()">'+ newstr + '</html>' + footer);
    popupWin.document.close(); 
    return false;
}
```

Comment: this good way to page size as A4 but how to crate page and border for per page ?

Comment: this may help u out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14397158/php-pdf-creation-a3-a4-and-a5

Answer (score 1):

The basis:

on your `CSS` print styles add a media query for printing and use the `@page` rule

```
@media print{
  @page {
    size: auto;   /* auto is the initial value */
    size: A4 portrait;
    margin: 0;  /* this affects the margin in the printer settings */
    border: 1px solid red;  /* set a border for all printed pages */
  }
}
```

> have php class for generate this ?

I dont think you really need extra libraries to do that. But, probably, you'll need some browser compatiblity... isn't?

**EDIT**

To support IE10+ you may want to add also this rule:

```
/* IE10+ CSS print styles */
@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
  /* IE10+ CSS print styles go here */
  @page {
    size: auto;   /* auto is the initial value */
    size: A4 portrait;
    margin: 0;  /* this affects the margin in the printer settings */
    border: 1px solid red;  /* set a border for all printed pages */
  }
}
```

You should be able to manage yourself with only CSS to print a website content.